# Android:inserting data

Tags: android, insert, android-sqlite

```
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254): Error inserting NUMEROSERIE=A485475D
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_traceur: , while compiling: INSERT INTO table_traceur(NUMEROSERIE) VALUES(?);
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.native_compile(Native Method)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compile(SQLiteProgram.java:110)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1027)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1413)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1286)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at com.sms.TraceurBDD.insertTraceur(TraceurBDD.java:44)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at com.sms.Acceuil.updatetracerliste(Acceuil.java:172)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at com.sms.Acceuil.onCreate(Acceuil.java:60)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-03 14:05:00.606: E/Database(254):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched the forums dealing with this issue but my concern persists.

Comment: Didnt you see this? no such table: table_traceur

Comment: Are you sure you have a table named table_traceur, if so; add more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your table **"table_traceur**" not found. Recreate the table before that you've to delete your application from the device.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
This is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot find the table "table_traceur"

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: table_traceur
```

You need to create that table before being able to insert in it

Comment: Thank you for your help.
This is resolved.

Comment: You are welcome. next time reward the first correct anwer